# AMD Ryzen 1600x for gaming in 1440 x 900

Tags: computer-building, amd-graphics-card, amd-ryzen

I want to build a PC for casual gaming. Here is my list:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 1600x
RAM: Two DDR-4 Ram Modules ( 2400 MHZ )

Do I need to buy a graphic card or Ryzen 1600x has a **built-in one**?

Comment: Current desktop Ryzen processors do not have an integrated graphics processor. A discrete graphics card is required.

Answer (score 0):

Ryzen 1600X is not an APU, hence it does not have a GPU in it.

Edit: found a clear marker, the APU family will be branded Ryzen Mobile. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryzen

Comment: I can add a link to AMDs website, but I don't know where it is clearly stated there. The fact is that it's a CPU, not an APU.

Answer (score -1):

I am almost certain that it ultimately depends on your choice of AM4 socket boards to put that CPU onto, but, Yes, you will need a graphics card.